# Print a Row only if the String exist in a specific Column

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Need help on an awk (or sed) command to select a row only if the Value/String Exist in a specific Column.

Example:

I only want to return the row if the word 'true' exist in column 5, do not bring the row back if 'true' does not exist in column 5

input:

```
john,jacob,jingle,schmidt,true
jason,jack,john,true,false
oscar,meir,true,weiner,false
tiffany,amber,false,theissen,true
jack,john,sally,true,true
```

Desired Output:

```
john,jacob,jingle,schmidt,true
tiffany,amber,false,theissen,true
jack,john,sally,true,true
```

I know how to 
pull a row back that has a word and doesnt have a word like this:

```
awk '/true/ && !/false/'
```

but that wont work
and I know how to remove a word only if its in a specific column

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/true */, "", $5)} 1'
```

but I do not know how to combine these two.

my best guess is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {"/true/",$5}
```

worst case scenario....:)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/true */, "Unmatchablestring", $5)} 1' | awk '/Unmatchablestring/'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F, '$5 == "true"' file
```

Comment: IMHO the requirement *... return the row if the word 'true' exist in column 5 ...* is fulfilled by the `~` operator

Comment: Hmm possibly but OP's input shows only word `true` in it that's why thought equality check will be more accurate.

Comment: so the difference between ~ and == ?

Comment: `~` is the *match* operator. It would also match something like `footruebar` while `==` is the equal operator which checks if the variable has exactly the literal value `true`. Your question indicated that you wanted to check whether the term `true` exists in `$5` but not `$5` contains the exact word `true` (and nothing more). However, after checking your demo data again, I would say that `==` is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was a bit vague about the fact if you want to check whether column 5 *contains* the literal value `true` or if it should be an exact match. If you want to check if column 5 *contains* `true` than use the match operator `~`, like this:

```
awk -F, '$5 ~ /true/' file
```

Otherwise follow [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31038112/171318).

Comment: @EdMorton Many thanks for that comment! I was already wondering about that. I did some tests and it "worked" like expected, but now I know why! I've changed that.

Comment: what was Ed Morton's Comment? Also in this instance, the Value could only be True or False in the 5th column. But I have another places to use a similar command like this. Thank you. If I wanted to do true or false in column 5 would I do:    awk -F, '$5 ~ /True/ & /False/'

Comment: @moore1emu My first version used `"true"` instead of `/true/`. While this would work too and being locally the same as the current version, it would produce unnecessary overhead since it would need to convert the string `"true"` into the pattern `/true/`. When I say *overhead*, I mean nanoseconds(!), so nothing really to worry about for you atm, but good to know for me. Ed mentioned that and I appreciated the comment.

Comment: @moore1emu If you want to allow true or false in column 5 you need: `awk -F, '$5 == "True" || $5 == "False`